# Joblib - how to parallelize modifying an variable in memory

Tags: python, joblib

I have a question regarding [joblib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/joblib). I am working with networkX graphs, and wanted to parallelize the modification of edges, since iterating over the edge list is indeed an embarrassingly parallel problem. In doing so, I thought of running a simplified version of the code.

I have a variable `x`. It is a list of lists, akin to an edge list, though I understand that networkX returns a list of tuples for the edge list, and has primarily a dictionary-based implementation. Please bear with this simple example for the moment.

```
x = [[0, 1, {'a': 1}],
     [1, 3, {'a': 3}]]
```

I have two functions that modifies the dictionary's `'a'` value to be either the addition of the first two values or a subtraction of the first two values. They are defined as such:

```
def additive_a(edge):
    edge[2]['a'] = edge[0] + edge[1]

def subtractive_a(edge):
    edge[2]['a'] = edge[0] - edge[1]
```

If I do a regular for loop, the variable `x` can be modified properly:

```
for edge in x:
    subtractive_a(edge) # or additive_a(edge) works as well.
```

Result:

```
[[0, 1, {'a': -1}], [1, 3, {'a': -2}]]
```

However, when I try doing it with joblib, I cannot get the desired result:

```
Parallel(n_jobs=8)(delayed(subtractive_a)(edge) for edge in x)
# I understand that n_jobs=8 for a two-item list is overkill.
```

The desired result is:

```
[[0, 1, {'a': -1}], [1, 3, {'a': -2}]]
```

When I check x, it is unchanged:

```
[[0, 1, {'a': 1}], [1, 3, {'a': 3}]]
```

I am unsure as to what is going on here. I can understand the example provided in the joblib documentation - which specifically showed computing an array of numbers using a single, simple function. However, that did not involve modifying an existing object in memory, which is what I think I'm trying to do. Is there a solution to this? How would I modify this code to parallelize the modification of a single object in memory?

Comment: The problem is very easily diagnosed: joblib forks multiple processes, with independent copies of your graph.

Comment: Thanks @larsmans! How would I then modify the code to parallelize the modification of the original graph? After all, modifying one edge doesn't affect another edge, which is why I thought to parallelize in the first place.

Comment: I don't think you can, or at least not in a way that will actually speed anything up. joblib is great when working with long computations on large NumPy arrays, not for this kind of task. It has a threading mode that allows this, but the threads won't run in parallel because they're all executing pure Python code (as opposed to Cython/C/C++/Fortran extension modules).

Comment: I see. Is there some other package that can handle this kind of task? I'm working with a fairly large graph right now, and iterating over ~3 million edges.

Comment: I think [graph-tool](http://graph-tool.skewed.de/) and [igraph](http://igraph.org/) should be able to handle that kind of graph, or use SciPy's sparse matrix package, that has some [graph algorithms](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.csgraph.html).